# MS Access 2007 - "ADO error: The specified schema name "Domain\username" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it"

Tags: ms-access

When I try to save a query (Specifically Stored Procedures and Functions) in MS Access, I get this error message:

> "ADO error: The specified schema name "DOMAIN\Username" either does
>   not exist or you do not have permission to use it" (Substituting
>   "Domain\Username for my actual username)

I can't figure out why it is treating my username as the schema name. The schema name should be "dbo"

I don't have this problem when I try to save a View. I can also add tables and do anything else in access without a problem.

I'm new to this company and also to access. We use Access as the front end for a SQL Server back end. My coworkers hadn't seen it before. (ODBC)